# Google oauth2 web-app vs javascript-app

Tags: javascript, python, google-oauth

I'm using python `REST APIs` in the backend and `javascript` in the frontend in my application.
So, for `Google oauth`, I can use either [WebApps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)  or [Client Side](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent).

Can anyone please explain which one will be better and why ?
Also, if using client-side, I'm concerned about hardcoding the app-id in javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to personal choice and the user experience you want to create.

Personally, I do the initial auth from my server app, but subsequent hourly refreshes using pure JavaScript. My reason for doing that was I found it a quicker way to get from Click to the loaded page including user information from my server database. If I downloaded the JS, then did the OAuth, and then used the id to fetch user info from the server, it took 3 times longer. My server runs on AppEngine, so I suspect I'm exploiting a shorter http path to Google's OAuth servers.

But to stress, it really comes down to the user experience and flow you want to achieve.